# ¿Cómo hacer un mensaje de alert personalizado con CSS?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Lo que quiero es personalizar el alert de javascript sin tener que dar en Aceptar para que se quite . Aquí una imagen de cómo tengo el alert sin estilos.
[image: Este alert quiero que solo aparezca y se quite solo sin tener que dar clic en aceptar]

lo único que tengo en el CSS es esto:

```
.holder-success{
background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Código HTML:

```
<div class="product-more-details">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-10">

            <input type="hidden" name="Articulo" id="Articulo" value="1"/>
            <input type="number" name="quanti"  id="quanti"  class="form-control"  value="1"/>

            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="quantity" 
            class="form-control" value="1"> <span id="Info"></span>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_urlImagen" id="urlImagen"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_codArticulo" id="codArticulo" 
             />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_codAlterno" id="codAlterno"
            />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_descrip" id="descrip" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price" />
        </section>
            <input type="button" name="add_to_cart" id="<?php echo $row["idArticulo"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info add_to_cart" value="Agregar al Carrito" />
    </div>

</div> <!--end product-more-details-->
```

En javascript tengo esto:

```
$(document).ready(function (data) {
i$('.add_to_cart').click(function () {
    var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var product_image = $('#urlImagen' + product_id).val();
    var product_codArticulo = $('#codArticulo' + product_id).val();
    var product_codAlterno = $('#codAlterno' + product_id).val();
    var product_descrip = $('#descrip' + product_id).val();
    var product_price = $('#price' + product_id).val();
    var product_quantity = $('#quantity' + product_id).val();

    var action = "add";
    if (product_quantity > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/action_cart_2.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                product_id: product_id,
                product_image: product_image,
                product_codArticulo: product_codArticulo,
                product_codAlterno: product_codAlterno,
                product_descrip: product_descrip,
                product_price: product_price,
                product_quantity: product_quantity,
                action: action
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#order_table').html(data.order_table);
                $('.badge').text(data.cart_item);
                alert("Ok: añadido al carrito"); //personalizar este alert con CSS
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Porfavor, eliga la cantidad de articulos"); //personalizar este alert con CSS
    }
});
});
```

Ahora, ¿dónde coloco la hoja de estilo para que muestre el mensaje personalizado?

Comment: O tienen alguna sugerencia de cómo personalizar ese mensaje

Comment: Debes saber que las alertas nativas del navegador no pueden ser estilizadas con CSS ni de ningún otro modo, por lo tanto la única opción que te queda es crearte una alerta casera con un poco de CSS y JavaScript lo tienes :)

Comment: Yo te recomiendo usar alguna librería como SweetAlert, magnifica para alertas.

Comment: si quieres hacer eso podrías tomar una sugerencia de este post: [hide-alert-box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15466856/8511744) pero mostrarías un div o algo con su respectivo class o id y lo muestras u ocultas con un setTime(..) en lugar de un alert.

Comment: @Pablo tomaré en cuenta tu respuesta

Comment: Los alert, prompt y confirm son creados por el navegador y sus estilos visuales dependen enteramente de éste. Por lo que
no es posible aplicar reglas de css para editar